# MDT Captured Win7 Image Crashes on Boot once Deployed

Tags: windows, windows-7, deployment, bsod, mdt

I am trying to get MDT set up for Windows 7 machines so that my life can be less hellish until we finish getting these machines out the door.

MDT Server:

Windows 2008 R2

MDT 6.3.8450.1000

WDS 6.1.7600.16385

I have no problems with Windows 10 deployments, even running MDT on an 2008 R2 server.

My Windows 7 Images seem to crash once deployed, during the first boot during the MDT process.  The PC fails two different ways:

If booting to Windows it BSODs with a Windows Stop 0x0000007E and crashes on ATIPCIE64.SYS

If attempting to boot in any form of Safe Mode it progresses one driver past ATIPCIE64.SYS and instead crashes on AMDKMPFD.SYS

I have tried a recent rebuild of my MDT image and added it to WDS with no change.

The image was created on a ProxMox VM.  The crashes occurs with any target device; if the image is deployed to a physical desktop or to another matching VM.

I'm curios if anyone has had an issue like this before and if there's something I need to do to the original VM I captured from to fix this, or if I need to fix the image itself?  Any help would be appreciated!